# How can one efficiently find the (x,y) values of the rectangles that enclose a chosen % of nonrandom data points in mathematica?

Tags: searching, counting

A half hour of searching for answers did not give useful results. 
This is typical data:

[image: x,y plot of nonrandom data points]

I need to find the (x,y) values of at least 6 rectangles with one corner at (0,0) and the opposite corner at (x,y) which enclose a defined percentage of all 10^6 data points.

4/20/18 Update:
I have added Carl Woll's code to the program. It gives a fast and accurate answer for the (x,y) values of the rectangles that enclose a chosen % of the data points. Here is the full code:

```
(*----------------------------------------------------------------*)
(*Remove all symbols*)
Remove["Global`*"];
(*--------------------------------*)
(*Side force data in kgF*)
forceside = 
  Round[{1.46372184`, 1.5154776`, 1.62452304`, 1.64008152`, 
    1.64888136`, 1.64924424`, 1.7485826400000002`, 
    1.9107900000000002`, 1.92067848`, 1.95651288`, 
    1.9618200000000001`, 2.02047048`, 2.0909145600000003`, 
    2.13232824`, 2.1611772`, 2.22912648`, 2.36516112`, 2.43143208`, 
    2.5262344800000003`, 2.57454288`, 2.61110304`, 2.66857416`, 
    2.7966708`, 2.93379408`, 3.24033696`}, 0.0001];
(*Assume rear force data is identical to side force data*)
forcerear = forceside;
(*Bottom force data in kgF*)
forcebottom = 
  Round[{1.67655096`, 1.73234376`, 1.8965016000000001`, 2.06723664`, 
    2.19692088`, 2.20885056`, 2.21420304`, 2.2199184`, 2.25389304`, 
    2.2695422400000003`, 2.42848368`, 2.62902024`, 2.65727952`, 
    2.76596208`, 2.95570296`, 3.15574056`, 3.25290168`, 
    3.5498735999999997`, 3.8103760799999997`, 3.88707984`, 
    4.00737456`, 4.1241312`, 4.34081592`, 4.56303456`, 4.57950024`}, 
   0.0001];
(*--------------------------------*)
(*set the Monte Carlo sample size *)
mccount = 10^6;
(*--------------------------------*)
(*Sample the pull locations*)
pulllocations = RandomChoice[{0.70, 0.16, 0.14} -> {0, 0, 1}, mccount];
(*Remove all the pull locations where the forces = 0*) 
nonzeropulllocations = DeleteCases[pulllocations, 0];
(*Sample the HDMI port orientations*) 
portorientations = 
  RandomChoice[{0.41206, 0.46231, 0.12563} -> IdentityMatrix[3], 
   Length[nonzeropulllocations]];
(*Separate out three lists for the three port orientations with \
nonzero pull forces and then remove the zeroes corresponding to pulls \
on other ports*)
portside = DeleteCases[portorientations[[All, 1]], 0];
portrear = DeleteCases[portorientations[[All, 2]], 0];
portbottom = DeleteCases[portorientations[[All, 3]], 0];
(*Sample the total number of cycles over 5 years for each customer \
with nonzero pulls*)
(*The five year bins are:*) 
fiveyearbins = {{0, 0}, {1, 109}, {110, 209}, {210, 409}, {410, 
    609}, {610, 809}, {810, 1009}, {1010, 1400}};
(*Assign the relative probabilities for a customer to be in each bin from the survey data*)
userprobabilities = {43, 36, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1};
(*set up eight bins (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} for one user to randomly fall \
into*)
oneuser = IdentityMatrix[8];
(*Sample the number of users falling into each five year bin*)
cyclenumbers =
  ParallelTable[
   (*Sample the numbers of users in each bin, for 88 users:*) 
   usersperbin = RandomChoice[userprobabilities -> oneuser, 88];
   (*add up how many users fell in each bin {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}*)
   usersamples = Total[usersperbin];
   (*Use these numbers to weigh a random choice of a single bin \
number*)
   randombin = RandomChoice[usersamples -> oneuser];
   (*For this random bin number; 
   randomly choose a corresponding number of cycles and output the \
result so it goes into the table*)   
   RandomInteger[randombin.fiveyearbins]
   (*repeat for all of the nonzero pull cases*)
   ,Length[nonzeropulllocations]];
(*assign each user one of these cycle numbers, deleting all zero \
cycle numbers*)
(*Portside*)
portsideallcycles = cyclenumbers[[1 ;; Length[portside]]];
portsidecycles = DeleteCases[portsideallcycles, 0];
(*Portrear*) 
portrearallcycles = 
  cyclenumbers[[
   Length[portside] + 1 ;; Length[portside] + Length[portrear]]];
portrearcycles = DeleteCases[portrearallcycles, 0];
(*Portbottom*)
portbottomallcycles = 
  cyclenumbers[[
   Length[portside] + Length[portrear] + 1 ;; 
    Length[portside] + Length[portrear] + Length[portbottom]]];
portbottomcycles = DeleteCases[portbottomallcycles, 0];
(*Sample the side force distribution parameters*) 
sidedist = LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
sideBootstrap := {\[Mu], \[Sigma]} /. 
      FindDistributionParameters[
    RandomChoice[forceside, Length[forceside]], sidedist];
sidesample = sideBootstrap;
sidemu = sidesample[[1]];
sidesigma = sidesample[[2]];
(*Sample the rear force distribution parameters*)
reardist = LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
rearBootstrap := {\[Mu], \[Sigma]} /. 
      FindDistributionParameters[
    RandomChoice[forcerear, Length[forcerear]], reardist];
rearsample = rearBootstrap;
rearmu = rearsample[[1]];
rearsigma = rearsample[[2]];
(*Sample the bottom force distribution parameters*)
bottomdist = LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
bottomBootstrap := {\[Mu], \[Sigma]} /. 
      FindDistributionParameters[
    RandomChoice[forcebottom, Length[forcebottom]], bottomdist];
bottomsample = bottomBootstrap;
bottommu = bottomsample[[1]];
bottomsigma = bottomsample[[2]];
(*Make a list of sequential forces for each nonzero force and nonzero \
cycle*)
(*sideforce*)
sideforcehistories = ParallelTable[
   RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[sidemu, sidesigma], 
    portsidecycles[[i]]]
   , {i, 1, Length[portsidecycles]}];
(*rearforce*)
rearforcehistories = ParallelTable[
   RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[rearmu, rearsigma], 
    portrearcycles[[j]]]
   , {j, 1, Length[portrearcycles]}];
(*bottomforce*)
bottomforcehistories = ParallelTable[
   RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[bottommu, bottomsigma], 
    portbottomcycles[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[portbottomcycles]}];
(*Combine all of the force histories into one list*)
nonzeroforcehistories = 
  Join[sideforcehistories, rearforcehistories, bottomforcehistories];
(*Restore all of the zero cycles and zero forces histories*) 
numberofzeroes = mccount - Length[nonzeroforcehistories];
allforcehistories = 
  Join[nonzeroforcehistories, ParallelTable[{0}, numberofzeroes]];
(*Find the max pull force for each nonzero force history:*)
maxstresses = Map[Max, nonzeroforcehistories];
(*The max event numbers of the nonzero force histories are the eventsamples numbers:*)
maxevents = Map[Length, nonzeroforcehistories];
(*Make a list of {maxevents,maxstresses} for all nonzero force histories:*)
maxeventsandstresses = Transpose[{maxevents, maxstresses}];
(*Count the number of {0,0} elements missing from {maxevents,maxstresses}:*)
numbermissing = mccount - Length[maxeventsandstresses];
(*make that many {0,0} elements*)
zeropairs = ParallelTable[{0, 0}, numbermissing];
(*Append these {0,0} elements to the list of maxeventsandstresses*)
fullmaxeventsandstresses = Join[maxeventsandstresses, zeropairs];
maxplot = 
  ListPlot[fullmaxeventsandstresses, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Full, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
(*--------------------------------*)
(*Input data, set cycle spec, and set reliability target in %:*)
pts = fullmaxeventsandstresses;
cyclespec = 110;
rtarget = 97.50;
(*--------------------------------*)
(*Carl Woll: Presort the points by y value for speed:*)
yFunction[pts_] := 
 yFunction[Length[pts], Sequence @@ Transpose@SortBy[pts, Last]]
yFunction[len_, xpts_, ypts_][percent_, x_] := 
 Module[{xin, yin}, xin = UnitStep[x - xpts];
  If[Total[xin] < percent len, $Failed, 
   Pick[ypts, xin, 1][[Floor[len percent]]]]]
(*The yFunction constructs a yFunction object that can be used to
find the y value for a given percent and x-value:*)
yf = yFunction[pts];
(*yf[target fractional reliability, target cycle number]:*)
stressspec = yf[rtarget/100, cyclespec];
Print[{cyclespec, stressspec}];
(*Calculate the actual reliability in %*)
reliability = 
  100.*Count[
     fullmaxeventsandstresses, {u_, v_} /; 
      u < cyclespec && v < stressspec]/mccount;
Print[reliability];
(*Envelope of spec box:*)
envelope = 
  Plot[yf[reliability/100, x], {x, 0, 1400}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
(*Plot the data and the envelope:*)
Show[maxplot, envelope]
(*--------------------------------*)
```

Comment: For a start, you can use `BinCounts` to collect the number of points in each reactangle...

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Use `Plot[yf[reliability/100, x], {x, 0, 1400}, PlotRange->All, PlotStyle -> Blue]` instead. Otherwise `Plot` stops plotting the function when the `y` value exceeds some automatically determined maximum.

Comment: @CarlWoll That works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated with faster method**

Here's a function that takes as arguments the points, the percent, and an `x`-value:

```
y[pts_, percent_, x_] := Module[{xin, yin},
    xin = UnitStep[x - pts[[All, 1]]];
    If[Total[xin] < percent Length[pts],
        $Failed,

        yin = Pick[pts[[All, 2]], xin, 1];
        yin[[First @ Ordering[yin, {Floor[Length[pts] percent]}]]]
    ]
]
```

Example showing timing for a million points:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10^6, 2}] . {{1, 0}, {0, 5}};

y[pts, .3, .8] //AbsoluteTiming
y[pts, .7, .2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.140796, 1.87733}
>
> {0.027093, $Failed}

**Presorting**

If we presort the points by `y` value, we can speed this up considerably. Here is an approach that does this.

```
yFunction[pts_] := yFunction[Length[pts], Sequence @@ Transpose @ SortBy[pts, Last]]

yFunction[len_, xpts_, ypts_][percent_, x_] := Module[{xin, yin},
    xin = UnitStep[x - xpts];
    If[Total[xin] < percent len,
        $Failed,

        Pick[ypts, xin, 1][[Floor[len percent]]]
    ]
]
```

The idea is that `yFunction` constructs a `yFunction` object that can be used to find the `y` value for a given percent and `x`-value. Here is the same example:

```
yf = yFunction[pts];

yf[.3, .8] //AbsoluteTiming
yf[.7, .2] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.021508, 1.87733}
>
> {0.00715, $Failed}

About 7 times faster.

**Visualizations**

Visualization of `y` vs `x`:

```
Plot[yf[.3, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Rectangle visualization for a different set of 1000 points:

```
SeedRandom[2]
pts = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}] . {{5, 0}, {0, 1}};
yf = yFunction[pts];

Graphics[{
    Green,
    Point[pts],
    FaceForm[None],
    EdgeForm[Red],
    Rectangle[{0, 0}, {#, yf[.2, #]}]& /@ Range[5]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: That is really helpful!

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney Do you mean it returns `$Failed`? An example would help. If you can't provide an example, then what does: `Total[UnitStep[x - pts[[All, 1]]]]` and `percent Length[pts]` return?

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney I was expecting you to evaluate those using the values of `x`, `percent` and `pts` that had an issue.

Comment: My error: your algorithm works correctly, but I was fooled by run-to-run statistical variations. I have amended the post accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please show me how to generalize your code to work on points in 3 dimensions? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
fraction = .5
n = 1000
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
xmin = Sort[pts[[All, 1]]][[Ceiling[fraction n]]]
y[x_, n_] := 
 Quiet@Check[ Sort[Select[pts, #[[1]] <= x  &][[All, 2]]][[n]], 0]
Graphics[{Point@
   pts, {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Red], Rectangle[ {0, 0}, #]} & /@
   Select[
    Table[ {x, y[x, Ceiling[fraction n]]}, {x, 
      Subdivide[xmin, 1, 6]}], #[[2]] > 0 &]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what the Quiet@Check step does?

Comment: `y[x,n]` would throw an error if `x` is too small (less than `xmin`) It just suppresses the error and makes the function return `0`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a straight forward, brute force solution. It returns the lower bounds of all the bins that meet your criteria. (Assuming I've read it correctly.)

```
HeaneysProblem[data_, maxDataValue_, binWidth_, percentage_] :=
  Module[ {binC, R, targetN},
   binC = BinCounts[data, {0, maxDataValue, binWidth},{0, maxDataValue, binWidth}];
   R = Accumulate[Map[Accumulate,binC]];
   targetN = Floor[percentage*Length[data]];
   Position[R, _?((targetN <= # < targetN + 1) &)]*binWidth
 ]

 CheckHeaneysProblem[data_, results_] := 
    Union[Map[CheckHeaneysProblem1[data, #] &, results]]
 CheckHeaneysProblem1[data_, {rx_, ry_}] := 
    Length[Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; x <= rx && y <= ry]]/Length[data]

 RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
 HeaneysProblem[%, 1, 0.01, 1/10];
 ListPlot[{%, %%}]
 CheckHeaneysProblem[%%%, %%]
```

[image]

EDIT: Runs much faster with Henrik Schumacher's suggestion of using "accumulate" instead of summation

Comment: I've tried without success to generalize this to points in 3 dimensions. Can you please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This generates some data to play with:

```
n = 1000000;
xa = 0.;
xb = 2.;
ya = 0.;
yb = 1.;
pts = Transpose[{RandomReal[{xa, xb}, n], RandomReal[{ya, yb}, n]}];
percentage = 10.;
threshold = Length[pts] percentage 0.01;
```

Now I split the whole rectangle into small reactangular bins and count the number of points in each bin with `BinCounts`:

```
xresolution = 2000;
yresolution = 1000;
counts = BinCounts[
  pts, 
  {xa, xb, (xb - xa)/xresolution}, 
  {ya, yb, (yb - ya)/yresolution}
 ];
```

`Accumate` provides an efficient way to sum up the number of pts in the rectangular region to the lower left of each bin.

```
accumulatedcounts = Accumulate[Accumulate /@ counts];
```

Now we substract the `threshold` and apply `UnitStep` and `Image` to obtain a black white image `img`. (Note that  compared to the original rectangle, the image appears rotated since the first coordinate axis in images points downward). A white pixel in `img` stands for a bin which has more than the desired `percentage` of points in its lower left rectangular; a black pixel indicates less than the `percentage` of points to the lower left. Finally, we detect the points on the border with `EdgeDetect` and read off the bin indices with `Position`.

```
img = Image@UnitStep[accumulatedcounts - threshold]
edges = EdgeDetect@img
idx = Position[ImageData[edges], 1];
```

Finally, we merely have to extract the upper right x-y-coordinates of the bins. I do it like this:

```
{i, j} = Transpose[idx];
binupperrightx = Rest[Subdivide[xa, xb, xresolution]];
binupperrighty = Rest[Subdivide[xa, xb, xresolution]];
result = Transpose[{binupperrightx[[i]], binupperrightx[[j]]}];
ListPlot[result, PlotRange -> {{xa, xb}, {ya, yb}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Because we apply rasterization, the method is not exact (we can improve upon that by increasing `xresolution` and `yresolution`), but it should suffice for every day applications.